# Configuring PowerShell prompt without profile

Tags: powershell

Primarily looking to configure a timestamp on PowerShell's prompt every launch, without using the profile.

I can use the '-Command' parameter to specify launch options for PowerShell. This successfully sets the prompt as desired when run from the unconfigured prompt:

```
function prompt{"PS " + " $(Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss") " + "[" + $env:UserName + "@" + $env:ComputerName + " " + $(Get-Location).Path.Split('\')[-1]+ "] >"}
```

However, when I place this within after the "-Command" parameter, I am misunderstanding something, because it ends up with a prompt that is just `PS>`

Thanks for any help figuring this out.

Comment: Why do you want to not use the profile?

Comment: Script execution GPO disabled even with admin access here, which blocks PS from loading profile. Since I just wanna add a timestamp mostly, I figure it's easiest to just modify the way I launch it.

Comment: You can temporarily change the execution policy.  Sounds like you need a PowerShell profile.

Comment: Any ideas why the prompt ends up "blank" `PS>` when passed through the `-Command` parameter?